# Syntax error: end of file

Tags: php

It's saying,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   /mnt/sdcard/www/parts/background/editProfilePic_Process.php on line 96

Can't find the error.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php

session_start();
$site="http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";
$root=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
if(substr($root,-1)!="/")
{
$root=$root."/";
}


 if(!isset($_SESSION["u"]))
{
header("location:".$site."user");
exit;
} 
 else{
$u=$_SESSION["u"];
}
 if(!isset($_POST["access"]))
{
echo "You cannot access this page";
exit;

} 
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php 
include($root."parts/resources.php");

?>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// header also contents the <noscript> alert 
include($root."parts/header.php");

?>
<div class="wholepage">

<div class="page scatterList">


 <?php 
if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
{
$name=$_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];

if($_FILES["profilePic"]["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
die("Upload failed with error code ".$_FILES["profilePic"]["error"]); 
} 

if(!getimagesize($_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]))
{
 exit;
}

$path=$site."img/1/".$u.".jpg";

move_uploaded_file($path, $_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]);
}
?>

</div> <!-- end of .page -->


</div> <!-- wholepage -->
<!-- FOOTER -->
<?php 
include($root."parts/footer.php");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to get rid of it?

Comment: Just try to debug. Seriously. That the only way to learn something.

Comment: your missing a `}` some where

Comment: With proper code indentation, these kinds of errors usually become much more apparent.

Comment: These type of errors are often caused by missplaced or excessive {}. In this case, it appears the IF block where you are checking if profilePic exists is not closed

Comment: This isn't a site for dumping your entire codebase and having others debug it for you.

Comment: the line error is from one of your includes

Comment: A good IDE would have prevented from being this question to be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close a brace on your **isset** if loop. Try this code.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $site="http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/";
    $root=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    if(substr($root,-1)!="/")
    {
        $root=$root."/";
    }


    if(!isset($_SESSION["u"]))
    {
        header("location:".$site."user");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        $u=$_SESSION["u"];
    }
    if(!isset($_POST["access"]))
    {
        echo "You cannot access this page";
        exit;

    }
    ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <?php
    include($root."parts/resources.php");

    ?>



</head>
<body>


<?php
    // header also contents the <noscript> alert
    include($root."parts/header.php");

    ?>
<div class="wholepage">

<div class="page scatterList">


<?php



    if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
            {
                $name=$_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];

                if($_FILES["profilePic"]["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    die("Upload failed with error code ".$_FILES["profilePic"]["error"]);
                }

                if(!getimagesize($_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]))
                {
                    exit;
                }

                $path=$site."img/1/".$u.".jpg";

                move_uploaded_file($path, $_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]);
            }

                ?>







            </div> <!-- end of .page -->


            </div> <!-- wholepage -->
            <!-- FOOTER -->
                <?php
                include($root."parts/footer.php");
                ?>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 48: begin if

```
if (isset ($_FILES["profilePic"])) {
```

`}` End tag not exist.

Put `}` tag after `move_uploaded_file` line 57 or where you want.

Like this:

```
if (isset ($_FILES["profilePic"])) {
   $name = $_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];
   if ($_FILES["profilePic"]["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES["profilePic"]["error"]);
   }

   if (!getimagesize($_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"])) { exit;}

   $path = $site . "img/1/" . $u . ".jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($path, $_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you haven't close this block

```
 if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't finish one of you if statements.

Change:

```
if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
{
$name=$_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];
```

to:

```
if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
{
$name=$_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php 
        if(isset($_FILES["profilePic"]))
        {
        $name=$_FILES["profilePic"]["name"];

        if($_FILES["profilePic"]["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die("Upload failed with error code ".$_FILES["profilePic"]["error"]); 
        } 

        if(!getimagesize($_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]))
        {
         exit;
        }

        $path=$site."img/1/".$u.".jpg";

        move_uploaded_file($path, $_FILES["profilePic"]["tmp_name"]);
        }// this one

        ?>
```

You never closed the first if statment..